# Vault Mismatch Error in Jboss/Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

We are getting the below error in Wildfly/Jboss when we are trying to encrypt the DB password using Vault. Can you provide a solution for this?

> Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: PB00027: Vault Mismatch:Shared Key does not match for vault block:bea_interface and attributeName:password

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible causes:

1). There is just a mismatch between the passwords. Check what you used when setting up the vault.

2). The encrypted password files are missing:
Aside of the keystore, you should not forget to put the two other files that vault.sh generates

```
vault.keystore
ENC.dat
Shared.dat
```

You need to copy all three files to the desired location, for example to the "standalone/configuration/" directory.
In the vault definition, these are the two paramaters that will tell JBoss where to find them:

```
<vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/vault.keystore"/>
<vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/"/>
```

3). You are using a keystore alias name longer then 10 characters.